# How to get a value back from an HttpRequest?

Tags: dart

I'm learning Dart and I've hit a roadblock. I very much want to return a value from a json string processing function so I can use that value inside main(). (I'm trying to set some top-level variables to use with a one-way data bind with an html template.) I'm using `HttpRequest.getString` and a `.then` call to kick off the processing. But HttpRequest doesn't like being assigned to a variable so I'm not sure how to get anything back out of it.

```dart
processString(String jsonString) {
  // Create a map of relevant data
  return myMap;
}

void main() {
  HttpRequest.getString(url).then(processString);
  // Do something with the processed result!
}
```

I guess my question is how do I get a value back from a function that was called from an HttpRequest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to do something that the Dart async model doesn't support.  You'll have to handle the result of the async request:

1. In `processString()`,
2. In another function called from `processString()`,
3. In an anonymous function passed to `then()`.

Or something similar.  What you *can't* do is access it from further down in `main()`:

```dart
processString(String jsonString) {
  // Create a map of relevant data
  // Do something with the processed result!
}

void main() {
  HttpRequest.getString(url).then(processString);
  // Any code here can never access the result of the HttpRequest
}
```

You may prefer:

```dart
processString(String jsonString) {
  // Create a map of relevant data
  return myMap;
}

void main() {
  HttpRequest.getString(url).then((resp) {
    map = processString(resp);
    // Do something with the processed result!
  });
  // Any code here can never access the result of the HttpRequest
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems I also can't change top-level variables from inside `HttpRequest`, even though it's within `main()`. Is this because I'm dealing with a `Future` that may have run after `main()`? Or am I hitting a scope problem?

Comment: @jacobrharris You can access (change) any top-level variables from the anonymous function or from `processString()`.  You won't see those changes from further down in `main()`, however, because the callback won't run until `main()` has completed.